# How to post on Facebook with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js

I just started messing around with Node.js and it's modules export and passport. After setting up login for Facebook, I'm stuck for hours how to post on my wall within the app. I've registered app on Facebook developers to get it's App ID and App Secret. I also registered it to localhost. How can I post now on Facebook?

This is my code so far:

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID:   APP_ID,
    clientSecret:   APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    /*
    User.findOrCreate(..., function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      done(null, user);
    });
    */
  }
));


var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world <a href="/auth/facebook">Login with Facebook</a>');
});

app.listen(3000);


// Redirect the user to Facebook for authentication.  When complete,
// Facebook will redirect the user back to the application at
//     /auth/facebook/callback
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

// Facebook will redirect the user to this URL after approval.  Finish the
// authentication process by attempting to obtain an access token.  If
// access was granted, the user will be logged in.  Otherwise,
// authentication has failed.
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/',
                                      failureRedirect: '/login' }
                        )
);
```

Once I'm logged, my URL looks something like:

```
http://localhost:3000/?code=AQAbQE...
```

This code variable is token, right?

Answer (score 0):

I had once used fb module it was really easy to use. very straight forward.
npm install fb